# How can I find minimum element of an integer in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, integer

Imagine we are getting input from user as integer. I want my code to return minimum and maximum numbers in this integer value. For example, if user enters 56389, the code should display

Minimum number: 3
Maximum number: 9

If user enters single digit integer, let's say 7, the output should be:

Minimum number: 7
Maximum number: 7

I am trying to declare input as String instead of integer and compare all elements of the String with charAt(i) method. However, I cannot get the result.

I would be glad if you can help me!

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about :), What do you want achive

Comment: @viking, Given an integer, the O/P wants to process the integer digit-by-digit, finding the digit with the greatest value and the digit with the minimum value.  Presumably, this is all in base ten.

Comment: One way to process an integer digit-by-digit is to use the division (`/`) and mod (`%`) operators:  If your number is `n`, the expression `j = n % 10` results in `j` having the value of the least significant (i.e., rightmost) digit.  `n = n / 10` chops off the least significant digit.

Comment: Please show an effort on your part before expecting anyone else to show one. BTW I would probably use a stream operation.

Comment: This was asked in midterm exam and I was not able to show effort. The only thing I did was to think input as string and use charAt(index) to compare numbers

Comment: Presumably, you have more time to attempt a solution now than you did during the midterm. It is expected here that your question should show an attempt.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
int number = Integer.valueOf(input);
int largest = 0;
int smallest = 9;

while(number != 0)
{
    int rem = number % 10;
    largest = Math.max(rem, largest);
    smallest = Math.min(rem, smallest);
    number = number / 10;
}
System.out.println(largest + " " + smallest);
```

Comment: This is close but fails when the input is 0 (it will report `smallest` as 9). You can fix this by switching to a `do {} while (number != 0)`, i.e. always passing at least once through the update code.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the string input using wrapper classes util methods. The rest of the code you can refer below.

```
int[] getLargestAndSmallestDigits(String in){
    int n = Integer.valueOf(in);
    if (n==0) {
        return new int[]{0,0};
    }
    int[] ans = {0,9};
    
    while(n != 0)
    {
        int r = n % 10;
        ans[0] = Math.min(r, ans[0]);
        ans[1] = Math.max(r, ans[0]);
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to work with the number representing it as a string, that means you'll have to be using the `charAt(int index)` method to retrieve an individual character from the string.

Then, to convert any number character (that is, '0', '1', '2' ... '9') to the number itself, subtract character `'0'` from it (`'0'` will be explicitly converted to int (ASCII code) at runtime), and you'll get the number itself in int representation.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char charNine = '9';
    int intNine = charNine - '0';
    System.out.println(intNine);
}
```

The output is `9`.